# android native calendar for my application - information should show under my app's name

Tags: android, mobile, calendar, native

I have to use android native calendar for my application data. And also I have to add milestones and also reminders to the events which I add through the app.
**I could found lot of tutorials to do those things.** But exactly what I need is, **I need to add the application's events separately from the other events to the calendar.**

When uninstalling the app the events also should remove from the calendar.

Users should be able to update and delete the events.

And I have a suggestion,but don't know is it a possible in android... Can I create separate account for the app in native calendar and take or view results with that account?.